How do I perform an ordered logistic regression with the R lme package?
I have longitudinal ordinal data and survival data. I want to do a joint model. I am familiar with the JM package, which uses lme for the longitudinal model. I theoretically understand that you can construct an ordinal logistic model serially from logistic models, but I haven't figured out the details of doing this in lme. Can it be done? Can it be faked? If so, how would I do it?
Thank you.

This sounds difficult. lme can't do generalized linear mixed models anyway, except via MASS::glmmPQL, and the machinery of setting up ordinal models is sufficiently tedious/tricky that I've never bothered. How good a computational statistician are you?

Well, I"ve done some programming in R beyond spaghetti coding, to produce a small application that could be used by non-statisticians.
